# How many values of a vector are divisible by 2? Use R

Tags: r, sum, logical-operators, integer-division

I have an ex. where I have to see how many values of a vector are divisible by 2. I have this random sample:

```
set.seed(1)
y <- sample(c(0:99, NA), 400, replace=TRUE)
```

I created a new variable d to see which of the values are or aren't divisible by 2:

```
d <- y/2 ; d
```

What I want to do is to create a logical argument, where all entire numbers give true and the rest gives false. (ex: 22.0 -> TRUE & 24.5 -> FALSE)

I used this command, but I believe that the answer is wrong since it would only give me the numbers that are in the sample:

```
sum(d %in% y, na.rm=T)
```

I also tried this (I found on the internet, but I don't really understand it)

```
is.wholenumber <- function(x, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5)  abs(x - round(x)) < tol
sum(is.wholenumber(d),na.rm = T)
```

Are there other ways that I could use the operator "%%"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can sum over the mod operator like so: `sum(1-y%%2)` or `sum(y%%2 == 0)`.  Note that `x %% 2` is the remainder after dividing by two which is why this solution works.

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly, I just added:    sum(y%%2 == 0, na.rm = T), since there are NA values in the sample.

Answer (score 2):

Here are three different ways:

1. `length(y[y %% 2 == 0])`
2. `length(subset(y, y %% 2 == 0))`
3. `length(Filter(function(x) x %% 2 == 0, y))`

Answer (score 2):

Since we're talking about a division by 2, I would actually take it to the bit level and check if the last bit of the number is a 0 or a 1 (a 0 means it would be divisible by 2).

Going out on a limb here (not sure how the compiler handles this division by 2) but think that would likely be more optimized than a division, which is typically fairly expensive.

To do this at the bit level, you can just do an AND operation between the number itself and 1, if result it 1 it means won't be divisible by 2:

```
bitwAnd(a, b)
```